# R Convert string vector to date with unusual date format

Tags: r, date

I am trying to convert a vector of factors to a vector of dates in R.  I know there are a number of questions on this topic, but I couldn't find an answer on how to convert this particular type of vector.

The data and my attempt is as follows:

```
dates <- c(1/4/2005, 1/5/2005, 1/6/2005, 1/7/2005, 1/8/2005, 1/9/2005, 1/10/2005)
class(dates)
 "factor"
dates <- as.character(dates)
class(dates)
 "character"
```

I then tried two approaches to convert from this string format to the date format using:

```
dates <- as.date(dates)  #This converts the vector to 0001-04-20, 0001-11-20, NA, NA, 0002-01-20,..
dates <- strptime(dates, "%m/%d/%y")  #This converts the vector to 2020-01-04, 2020-01-02, ...
```

I believe it is because the date column is saved with single numbers for each month and day, e.g. "1" instead of "01" for the month and "5" instead of "05" for the day.  Is there a way to convert this character vector to the correct date format?  Thank you.

Comment: `as.Date(dates, format="%m/%d/%Y")` or `as.Date(dates, format="%d/%m/%Y")` (your example dates are ambiguous)

Comment: Is you vector `c(1/4/2005, 1/5/2005, 1/6/2005, 1/7/2005, 1/8/2005, 1/9/2005, 1/10/2005)` really a `factor`? The way you have entered them, they are `numeric`; 1 divided by 4, divided by 2005 et c. Did you mean `c("1/4/2005", "1/5/2005", "1/6/2005", "1/7/2005", "1/8/2005", "1/9/2005", "1/10/2005")`

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Your dates are numeric, i.e., 1/4/2005 equals (1/4)/2005 = 1.24E-4

Problem 2: You need "%Y" for 4-digit-years (%y is for 2-digit-years)

This should work:

```
dates <- c("1/4/2005", "1/5/2005", "1/6/2005", "1/7/2005", "1/8/2005", "1/9/2005", "1/10/2005")
strptime(dates, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dates are the short date format (maybe from Excel), which is what I encounter most of the time when the data is exported from excel to csv and read into R via read.csv.

```
dates <- c("1/4/2005", "1/5/2005", "1/6/2005", "1/7/2005", "1/8/2005")
df <- data.frame(dates = dates) # emulate df = read.csv(file)
```

Then you would want to add a Date column to df by

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$dates, format="%m/%d/%Y")    
df
     dates       Date
1 1/4/2005 2005-01-04
2 1/5/2005 2005-01-05
3 1/6/2005 2005-01-06
4 1/7/2005 2005-01-07
5 1/8/2005 2005-01-08
```

You can then use the Date column for timeseries manipulation, e.g. through xts.